# why visualize is not defined in visualize.js using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im using angularjs to view jasper report. When I use jsFiddle it work and display the report but when I transfer it to my project didn't work and here is my error.

[image]

it doesn't recognize the visualize.

What does this error means? I already have jQuery in my project.

Thank you so much.

Update:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="jasperSample" class="col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
visualize({
            auth: {
                name: "myUserName",
                password: "myPassword",
                organization: "myOrganization"
            }
        },
         function (v) {
             //render report from provided resource
             v("#jasperSample").report({
                 resource: "/public/Samples/Reports/01._Geographic_Results_by_Segment_Report",
                 error: handleError
             });
             //show error
        function handleError(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
     });
```

I also include the visualize.js like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myserver/jasperserver-pro/client/visualize.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle and some code please ?

Comment: yup wait ill update..

Comment: hi @AmadouBeye I already updated with code. thats the format of the code I use in fiddle and in my project. Thanks.

Comment: but visualize is undefined and I don't know why..